Is it possible to have a named range attached to "activesheet," rather than a specific sheet?
Is it possible to name a range without it being slaved to a single sheet? Like if I select "rnge1" on sheet 1, it will select range e2:e7 on sheet 1, and then I can go to sheet 2 and select "rnge1" and it will select range e2:e7 on sheet 2.
I'd like to use the named ranges I have in a single macro attached to a button. I have 1 button on each of 10 sheets. The ranges (rnge1, rnge2, rnge3) encompass e2:e7, e213:e184, e281:e284. I like using the named ranges because they automatically update when a row is added in the sheet, versus going into VBA to update it every time. I'd prefer to not have to make named ranges for each page.
When I try to remove the sheet name (='MON (1)'!$E$2:$E$7) so that it looks like this: =$E$2:$E$7, it just reverts back to the one with the sheet name. The issue with this is that when I click the button on sheet 2, it runs the macro on sheet 1. I've also tried "=activesheet.range(e2:e7)", which I found on another post, but it just causes an error.
here is a copy of the code for reference:
Sub DELETE_E()
 Dim ws As Worksheet, rng As Range
 Range("RNGE3").ClearContents
 Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set rng = ws.Range("RNGE2")
 With rng
    .Formula = Evaluate("IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "),8)=""=Left($B"","""",FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "))")
    .Formula = Evaluate("IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "),7)=""=MISC.!"","""",FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "))")
    .Formula = Evaluate("IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "),3)=""=$B"","""",FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "))")
    .Formula = Evaluate("IF(LEFT(FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "),7)=""=MID($B"","""",FORMULATEXT(" & rng.Address & "))")
    On Error Resume Next
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
  End With
   Set ws = ActiveSheet: Set rng = ws.Range("RNGE1")
   With rng
    On Error Resume Next
     .SpecialCells(xlCellTypeConstants).ClearContents
    On Error GoTo 0
    End With
 End Sub


Try =activesheet.range("E2:E7") (the range address has to be in quotes)

@cybernetic.nomad no dice...

So... i need to ask after I typed up a comment, @Quasar ... "r1" is r1 or `Range("R1") and links to another range?

You can create a Name with Sheet rather than Workbook scope. eg if you have Sheet1 with a Name "Fred" referring to cell $A$1, you can define the name as "Sheet1!Fred". If you duplicate that sheet to be a new Sheet2, then Sheet2 will have a name "Sheet2!Fred" referring to cell $A$1 on Sheet2. In the macro code ActiveSheet.Range("Fred").Value will return whatever is in cell $A$1 of the active sheet.

Could this be an option: define the range with workbook scope and read the address with Range.Address and apply it to the active sheet?

@Cyril "r1" is the name of the range e2:e7

@Quasar i feel like something is missing, as one cannot utilize an existing cell reference as their named range, e.g., "r1" being input would refer to R1 and selects that cell.  When I typed up an answer and utilization I referenced Cells(1,"R") due to said rationale.  I wonder now if it isn't a difference of like r1c1 notation or something.

@Cyril you're right, I updated my original post to include the code I am using.

Having a name ("MyName") with "Sheet1" as scope, you can use its address in the active sheet in the next way:
 Dim rng as Range
 Set rng = Range(Range("MyName").address)
 rng.Select

It will select in the active sheet the range defined for "MyName", even referring "Sheet1" as scope.

So this is going to be a bit of a dump... there are lots of ways to reference ranges in VBA, or just define ranges; e.g.:
dim currentNamedRange as range
set currentNamedRange = ThisWorkbook.Name("namedRange").RefersToRange 'uses a named range in the whole workbook and finds its location
set currentNamedRange = ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1).Range("E2:E7") 'uses a specified range on a sheet
set currentNamedRange = Range("E2:E7") 'a range with no qualifications, meaning it is the active sheet

Similar to setting up the named ranges by selecting them and labeling, you could also define each range in VBA and use other events, per sheet, to interact with the reference, e.g.:
Public currentNamedRange as range

Private Sub Worksheet_BeforeDoubleClick(Target As Range, Cancel As Boolean)
    Select Case Target
        Case Cells(1,"R")             
            Set currentNamedRange = Range("E2:E7")
        Case Cells(2,"R")             
            Set currentNamedRange = Range("E213:E184")
        Case Cells(3,"R")             
            Set currentNamedRange = Range("E281:E284")
        Case Else
            Exit Sub
    End Select
End Sub


will the ranges automatically update if a row is added to e5?

@Quasar looks like Fane beat me to typing the next part... (removed previous comment made).  The question that comes up after is if RNGE1 on sheet1 having an increased row is guaranteed to affect all other sheets, or if RNGE1 on sheet2 will still be "E2:E7" rather than "E2:E8"`

I appreciate the help! typically when I add a row to one sheet, I add it to all of them, so if it becomes an issue, ill try to figure it out and report back here.

We can using INDIRECT to have a Range reference that is not scoped to any particular worksheet.  The advantage of the approach over Range(Range("rnge1").Address) is that they will work no matter what worksheet is deleted.
In this example, I added 3 named ranges to the Workbook Names collection.  They will work regardless of which worksheet they are qualified to.
Sub AddAndTestNamedRanges()
    Rem Add the Named Ranges to the Workbook
    Rem So they can work across multiple sheets.
    With ThisWorkbook.Names
        .Add Name:="rnge1", RefersToR1C1:="=INDIRECT(""E2:E7"")"
        .Add Name:="rnge2", RefersToR1C1:="=INDIRECT(""E213:E184"")"
        .Add Name:="rnge3", RefersToR1C1:="=INDIRECT(""E281:E284"")"
    End With

    Rem Test the Named Ranges
    Debug.Print Sheet1.Name, Sheet1.Range("rnge1").Address(External:=True)
    Debug.Print Sheet2.Name, Sheet2.Range("rnge2").Address(External:=True)
    Debug.Print Sheet3.Name, Sheet3.Range("rnge3").Address(External:=True)
End Sub


